# how to plot attention vector on tensorboard graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Attention vector for sequence 2 sequence model is basically a array of shape [batch_size, time_step,1], which indicates the weighs of a particular time step.

But if I use `tf.summary.histogram` to show it on tensorboard, tensorflow will only show the distributions of weights, I can't tell the which time step is more important. I can use `tf.summary.scalar`, but length of my source sequence is 128 , it is too much plots. The most nature way of show this kind of data it a picture like this, but how can I do it in tensorboad?

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand the picture. How does it show the two dimensional attention array? Does it reduce on the batch dimension? Is the x-axis time_step?

Comment: yes. the x-axis is time_step, y is the weights for this time-step.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorboard does not currently support visualizing tensor summaries. There is a [summary op](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/tensor_summary) for it, but Tensorboard will just skip it when reading summaries from disk at the moment. I am also not aware of any third party plugins that support this, though it is very much doable.

In your plot, it seems like there are only 19 time steps. One way is to create 19 scalar summaries. Alternatively, you can use tf.summary.tensor_summary op, but process the tensorboard event file (containing this data) with your own script.